# Read a file char by char and store data to a bidimentional array C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a file called `map.txt`, that looks like :

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x  Ox xx         x
x  xx xx xxxxxx  x
xx            x  x
x xxxx  x  x  x  x
x       x     x  x
x  x    x  x  x  x
x  x             x
x  x    x  x  x  x
x                x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It represents a maze. I have to read this file char by char and store it in a bidimensional array `char data [][]` but i'm having problems to use `fgetc`. here is my code:

```
int readMapFromFile(char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    char element;
    printf("reading map from file %s...\n", filename);
    int c;

    if(file == NULL)
        return 1;

    int j =0;
    int i =0;

    while((c = fgetc(file))!= EOF) {
        element = (char) c;
        if(element == '\n') {
            j = 0;
            i++;
            continue;
        } else if(element == 'O') {
            player.exitX = j;
            player.exitZ = i;
        }
        data[i][j] = element;
        j++;
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to skip the whitespaces and i have no idea how to make it work.
As request i added how i display the data's content:

```
int i;
int j;
for (i =0 ; i < map.x ; ++i);
{
    for(j = 0 ; j < map.z ; ++j) {
        printf("%s \n", &data[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Expected output :

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x  Ox xx         x
x  xx xx xxxxxx  x
xx            x  x
x xxxx  x  x  x  x
x       x     x  x
x  x    x  x  x  x
x  x             x
x  x    x  x  x  x
x                x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

My output :

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxOxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

As you can see not the entire maze is saved.

Comment: what makes you think it skips the spaces, the code looks ok to me

Comment: And why not read line by line using `fgets`, and to find the player position just go through the data afterwards?

Comment: Ops , i made a mistake . the function is fgetc not scanf

Comment: I don't see any direct problem with your code, how do you know it "seems to skip whitespace"? Are there tabs in the `map.txt` file? Have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger to make sure it does what you expect it to do?

Comment: @codebox when i print data's content i only get a lot of x without space.

Comment: Maybe you should show us how you print the map? Do you modify the data in any way between reading and printing it? Can you please try to  create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: i will add how i print the map in the post.

Comment: you do not increase `j` in the `while` loop.

Comment: "fgetc() reads the next character from stream and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error."
I think you do not use it's return value as its best. 
Therefore, j is never incremented.

Comment: You have undefined behavior in your output of the map. You print each character as a string, and strings are supposed to have a string terminator, which you don't have. Use `"%c"` to print the characters.

Comment: @HaZe it's time for you to learn how to user a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about skipping whitespace. You just never increment `j`.

The code in the `if(element == '\n')` statement should be like this:

```
if(element == '\n'){
    j++;
    i = 0;
    continue;
}
```

If you had named your variables `x` and `y` instead of `i` and `j`, you probably would have found out by yourself.

And your map display function is totally wrong, it should be:

```
  int i;
  int j;

  for (i = 0 ; i < map.x ; ++i) {
    for(j = 0 ; j < map.y ; ++j) {
      printf("%c", data[i][j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }
```

Comment: Even with you code i only get xxxxx from printf , i've used a debugger and data is filled right. I don't know why but the i variable have value set to map.x .

Comment: @HaZe `for (i =0 ; i < map.x ; ++i);` -- Notice the `;` at the end. This is an empty loop, which runs before the `j` loop.